# is it possible to determine whether the current VM is Java SE or Dalvik?

Tags: java, android

I wish to implement something looks like this:

```
if(isJavaVirtualMachine()){
    System.out.println("You are running on a JVM");
}else if(isDalvikVirtualMachine()){
    Log.i("env","You are running on an android.");
}
```

Is it possible? If its impossible by Java itself, can I do it by JNI?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `System.getProperty`. The property names for Dalvik are documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

As ykaganovich pointed out, it should be pretty easy to distinguish between plain Java and Android at runtime.
The other problem is that you won't have Android specific classes like *Log* in a plain Java environment, so you will run into problems at runtime!
A possible solution would be to assemble platform specific adapters using reflection, so you pull in the dependencies only at runtime (might be somewhat tricky).